# Jquery UI autocomplete select

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I need some help with the code below.

```js
$("#auto_cp").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    //source
    source: function(req, add) {
        $.getJSON("friends.php?callback=?", req, function(data) {
            var suggestions = [];
            $.each(data, function(i, val) {
                suggestions.push(val.name);
            });
            add(suggestions);
        });
    },
    //select
    select: function(e, ui) {
        alert(ui.item.value);
    }
});​
```

using FireBug, i'm getting this in my console :

> jQuery171003666625335785867_1337116004522([{"name":"97300 
>   Cayenne","zzz":"203"},{"name":"97311 
>   Roura","zzz":"201"},{"name":"97312 Saint 
>   Elie","zzz":"388"},{"name":"97320 Saint Laurent du 
>   Maroni","zzz":"391"},{"name":"97351 
>   Matoury","zzz":"52"},{"name":"97354 Remire MontJoly 
>   Cayenne","zzz":"69"},{"name":"97355 Macouria Tonate","zzz":"449"}])

Everything is working very fine, but I don't know how to get the value of 'zzz' on select item.

I tried

```
alert(ui.item.zzz);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you see in the alert popup?

Comment: In the alert popup i see : undefined

Comment: And what do you see if you do `alert(ui.item)` in the select function?

Comment: doing alert(ui.item) i get : [object Object]

Comment: Try console.log(ui.item); in Chrome
Should show the full object structure.

Comment: :( my autocomplete simply doesn't work in Chrome!

Answer (score 8):

The autocomplete widget expects a data source in array format with either:

- Objects containing a **label** property, a **value** property, or both
- Simple string values

You are currently building up the second (an array of string values), which works fine, but you can also slightly tweak your data as you iterate over it and also supply the other properties in the object:

```
$("#auto_cp").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    //source
    source: function(req, add) {
        $.getJSON("friends.php?callback=?", req, function(data) {
            var suggestions = [];
            $.each(data, function(i, val) {
                suggestions.push({
                    label: val.name,
                    zzz: val.zzz
                });
            });
            add(suggestions);
        });
    },
    //select
    select: function(e, ui) {
        alert(ui.item.zzz);
    }
});​
```

Now, since the array you're supplying the widget contains objects with a **name** property, you should get autocomplete functionality and also gain access to the `zzz` property.

**Here's a working example** (without the AJAX call): http://jsfiddle.net/LY42X/

Comment: Hello, i've tryed your solution upper and i still get "undefined".
Ok for your working exemple, but i have to make it work with the ajax call.
Could you help?

Comment: What's the URL you're using? Since you're making a JSONP call I can probably make JSFiddle use the same URL.

Comment: ok i make it work using your solution.
I simply do : alert(ui.item.zzz);
Et voilà!!

Comment: @user367864: Ah! I'm so sorry that was a typo in my answer, I've corrected it.

Comment: I don't know if you intended to make a working example or just the object being parsed properly, but typing on the search box returns ALL the results. The results shown should be only the ones matching the text entered, should they not?

Comment: @sergio: Since this is just supposed to show how to construct a response that the widget can work with, no filtering is occurring. Normally this would happen in server-side code.

Answer (score 2):

You're source function is only populating the name. If you want everything from that data structure, do this:

```
$("#auto_cp").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    //source
    source: function(req, add) {
        $.getJSON("friends.php?callback=?", req, function(data) {
            var suggestions = [];
            $.each(data, function(i, val) {
                suggestions.push(val); //not val.name
            });
            add(suggestions);
        });
    },
    //select
    select: function(e, ui) {
        alert(ui.item.value.zzz);
    }
});​
```

Comment: Hmm, i have try this, but it broke my autocomplete.
I mean, when starting typing i get no results.
I can see the "response" in Firebug but as far as i can see, val.name is not dispayed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an array of objects... what your may be missing is the "[0]" or in general "[index]".

Please check this: [jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select)

Comment: It doesn't work also
Yes it is an array, here is the php code of the file i'm calling via ajax

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT cv_ville,cv_numville FROM cms_code_ville WHERE cv_ville LIKE '%".$_GET['term']."%'");
 
    //build array of results
    for ($x = 0, $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query); $x < $numrows; $x++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $friends[$x] = array("name" => $row["cv_ville"] , "zzz" => $row["cv_numville"]);
    }
 
    //echo JSON to page
    $response = $_GET["callback"] . "(" . json_encode($friends) . ")";
    echo $response;

Comment: Ahh, but what if you use: alert(ui[0].zzz) ??

Comment: This is firing once you select something. So "ui.item" is supposed to be the select item... or null if nothing is selected.  So, you could check if ui.item is nothing to then retrive its property.  In your json... you have "name" and "zzz"... so you could do "ui.item.name" or "ui.item.name.value".